# Name collisions between types and variables in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm using ImmutableJS(4.0.0-rc.12) and the Flow type checker.  I created my project [using create-react-app like so](https://flow.org/en/docs/tools/create-react-app/).

I'd like to define a type where the factory and the type it produces have the same name.

```
// @flow
type PointProps = {x: number, y: number}
const defaultPoint: PointProps = {x: 0, y: 0}
export const Point = Record(defaultPoint)
export type Point = RecordOf<PointProps>
```

I would think that type names and variable names would be tracked separately by the compiler.  However, babel says `Duplicate declaration "Point"` and flow says `Duplicate export for Point`.

Is there a reason why these names aren't tracked separately?  Is this a feature I could hope for some day?